# Dense 3D reconstruction using Thin-Plate Splines

Tags: 3d-reconstruction

I have a question about Dense reconstruction using Thin-Plate Splines interpolation. I have two images, then I detect some features using SURF (sparse reconstruction). These points were used to initialize the interpolation which seems good. So, I have two grids of corresponding points. The problem consists in fact that the triangulation of these grid points gives a very bad result in termes of dense reconstruction... In 3D, I obtain the same 2D grid but in 3D. Unfortunately I can't put images directly in my message, but you can find them here :

[Results of sparse reconstruction](http://image.openlan.ru/images/19828966288468758846.jpg)

[Incorrect dense reconstruction](http://image.openlan.ru/images/23275923839394942732.jpg)

My question is : what am I doing wrong? Should I assign features to new interpolated points and then match them again?

Thank you in advance !